# How to get $\begin{vmatrix}\\a_i-a_j \end{vmatrix}<1/N$?

Tags: real-analysis

This is from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis and solution is from internet.

The theorem and proof are:

[image]

My question is :
How to get $\begin{vmatrix}\\a_i-a_j \end{vmatrix}<1/N$ ?

Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: That proof is poorly written. The use of the pigeon hole principle should be at least stated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dividing the interval $[0,1]$ into $N$ equal subintervals $[0,1/N], [1/N,2/N], \ldots, [1-1/N, 1]$. You have $N+1$ points - so by the [Pigeon-hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), it follows that at least two of those points must be in the same sub-interval. ie. two of those points cannot differ by more than $1/N$.